# How to slice to a multiple of N?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `bytes` object, and I need to slice it into the part that is the multiple of 16 and the remainder. For example, if it's length is 35, I would need this:

```
whole_blocks = buf[:32]
remainder = buf[32:]
```

I could obviously do

```
split_at = 0 - (len(buf) % 16)
whole_blocks = buf[:split_at]
remainder = buf[split_at:]
```

but it feel like there should be a better way that I am missing, without the extra variable. Is there?

Comment: What would you like to do with the parts?  Do you want to iterate over the whole blocks?

Comment: @SvenMarnach I am using a module that encrypts (AES) only multiples of whole blocks

Comment: Isn't the usual way to deal with this problem to pad the string to the next multiple of 16 rather than to strip off a remainder?  Doesn't the module you are using support padding schemes?

Comment: Yeah, how are you going to encrypt the remainder block? Better pad it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach The remainder will be encrypted as in ANSI/SCTE 52, by rencrypting the last whole block and xor-ing the result with the remainder. I don't have a say in this (I am interfacing with an existing protocol)

Comment: Fair enough, just wanted to make sure we are solving the right problem here.  I don't think you can do much better than what you have.  You can omit the redundant `0`, or you could use `split_at = len(buf) & -16` if you like cryptic code. :)

Comment: What you have is pretty straight forward (other than the you can drop the `0` in the `split_at` expression).  Why do you think there should be an easier way?